# Trying to pass object through another function, coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the data from this one function, fetched from an API, into another. But the data does not want to carry over. Can you help? It keeps coming back as undefined. When I console log it in the other function, it just returns  "object object" over and over.

Much appreciated.

```js
app.getDisruptionData = () => {
  $.ajax ({
    url: "https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/5yvt-mcye.json",
    method:"GET",
    dataType: "json", 
    data: {
      "$limit" : 500000,
      "$$app_token" : "J33yX1FYA0vwnOA36tGBFLd6l"
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      setTimeout(app.getDisruptionData, 300000);
      $serviceDisruptions.empty();
    
      const htmlToAppend = 
      `<li class="stationGrid"> 
        <div> 
          ROUTE
        </div>
        <div> 
          DESCRIPTION 
        </div>
        <div> 
          DISRUPTION START
        </div>
        <div> 
          EXPECTED END TIME
        </div>
      </li>`
    
    $serviceDisruptions.append(htmlToAppend);
    }
  }).then((response) => {

    console.log(response)

    app.sortDisruptions(response)

    //  response.forEach ( (disruptionObject) => {
    //    const routeID = disruptionObject.route_ID;
    //    const routeName = disruptionObject.route_long_name;
    //    const disruptionStart = disruptionObject.start_dttm;  
   // })

  });
}

app.sortDisruptions = (data) => {
  console.log(`look at this data ` + data)
}
```

Comment: _"this one function"_... which of the many functions in your question is the _one_?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's promise-like handling can be a bit weird. Also, `complete` doesn't receive data, only the `jqXhr` object and a text status.

I would consolidate your `complete` and `then` callbacks into a single [done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

```js
$.getJSON("https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/5yvt-mcye.json", {
  $limit: 500000,
  $$app_token: "J33yX1FYA0vwnOA36tGBFLd6l",
}).done((data) => {
  setTimeout(app.getDisruptionData, 300000);

  // setting html is the same as empty + append
  $serviceDisruptions.html(
    `<li class="stationGrid"> 
        <div> 
          ROUTE
        </div>
        <div> 
          DESCRIPTION 
        </div>
        <div> 
          DISRUPTION START
        </div>
        <div> 
          EXPECTED END TIME
        </div>
      </li>`
  );

  app.sortDisruptions(data);
});
```

Also, try not to concatenate objects to strings in logging. A stringified object almost always displays as `[object Object]`

```js
app.sortDisruptions = (data) => {
  console.log("sortDisruptions", data);

  // or just
  console.log(data);
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked! Is there a reason why I have have console log both "sortDisruptions" and "data" in order to retrieve that data?

Comment: You don't have to console log anything. In fact, I recommend using `console.log()` as little as possible. Adding a string label to your logging helps identify where the log came from but it's entirely optional. You could just use `console.log(data)` if you want

Comment: When i console.log data only it gives me undefined again. Just wanted to figure out why because I intend to do more stuff with that data in the new function and was wondering if I would need to use sortDisruptions.data when doing so.

Comment: You said in your first comment above that it worked? There's no fundamental difference between `console.log("sortDisruptions", data)` and `console.log(data)`

Comment: Yes console.log("sortDisruptions", data) returned the objects I was looking for, but console.log(data) still comes back as undefined. I was console logging to see how to structure my code was going forward, and to make sure that the data was actually being passed through to the new function.

Comment: That is quite literally impossible

Comment: ... asumming the two lines are in the same place.  If your `console.log(data)` is outside the scope of the data then it will be undefined.